# React: setter methods seem not working in functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm okay working with class components, but I cannot understand how setters work in functional components, this is my code (clipped for simplicity), when I click on the Add item button the method is called but nothing happens, seems like the component is re rendered and detail returns to the initial state (not sure, just guessing).

```
const Default = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
    }, []);

    const [detail, setDetail] = useState([]);
    const addProduct = (e) => {
        const d = newItem?
                {
                    quantity: 1,
                    price: 0
                }
        setDetail([...detail, d]);
    };

    return <div>
            <Button onClick={addProduct}>Add item</Button>
         <Table>
         <TableHead>
           <TableRow>
             <TableCell style={{width: 60}}>#</TableCell>
             <TableCell style={{width: 60}}>Qty</TableCell>
             <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
             <TableCell style={{width: 120}}>Price</TableCell>
           </TableRow>
         </TableHead>
         <TableBody>
           {detail.map((x,i) => (
             <TableRow key={i}>
               <TableCell>{i+1}</TableCell>
               <TableCell>
                 <TextField value={x.quantity}
                     onChange={e => {handleQtyChange(e,i)}}
                 />
               </TableCell>
               <TableCell>
                 <TextField value={x.price}
                     onChange={e => {handlePriceChange(e,i)}} 
                 />
               </TableCell>
             </TableRow>
           ))}
         </TableBody>
       </Table>
      </div>
```

I've tried with push method but neither works, please help me.

Comment: what is newItem?

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox example, addProduct code needs to be checked

Comment: undefined variable `newItem`, incomplete ternary `? :` should both cause runtime error so `setDetail` is not even called. If real code looks different, make sure it's reflected in the post. Also all unrelated JSX does not help. Finally, I'd like to ask you define "not working". Depending on what you expect, when and where answer will be different